# Convert binary values to a decimal matrix

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, binary

Suppose that I have a matrix a= [1 3; 4 2], I convert this matrix to binary format using this code:

```
a=magic(2)
y=dec2bin(a,8)
e=str2num(y(:))';
```

The result is :

```
  y =

00000001
00000100
00000011
00000010


e =

Columns 1 through 17

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0         0     0     0     0

Columns 18 through 32

 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0        1     0
```

Now when I want to get back my original matrix I inverse the functions :

```
  s=num2str(e(:))';
  r=bin2dec(s)
```

The results I got is:

```
r =

    1082
```

What can I do to get the orignal matrix? not a number
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the right solution for my problem and I want to share it in case anyone need it :

```
a_back=reshape(bin2dec(num2str(reshape(e, 4, []))), 2, 2)

a =

 1     3
 4     2
```

Answer (score 6):

You are doing extra processes which destroyed the original structure:

```
a=magic(2)
y=dec2bin(a,8)
r=bin2dec(y)
```

Here r is your answer since y has removed the matrix structure of a. To recreate your matrix, you need to:

```
originalmatrix = reshape(r,size(a))

originalmatrix =

 1     3
 4     2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but your answer gave me the matrix values with different position. the original matrix 'a=[1 3;4 2]' but the function 'vect2mat' changes the position of 3 and 4 if you noticed it

Comment: Completely did not notice it :D your method of reshape is the correct way to do it. I have also corrected my solution.